# MYSQL match multiple rows across same table with multiple ids

Tags: mysql, sql, match, where-in

I'm working out a way to process orders where I would have to satisfy the order from multiple vendors, and I want to know which 2 vendors could supply the given order.

The product_ids in my order are 10,20,30,40,50

```
SELECT * 
  FROM vendors 
 WHERE product_id IN (10,20,30,40,50)
```

gives me all vendors who have at least 1 of the products

```
vendor_id | product_id 
1234          10
1234          20
1234          30
1234          40
1235          10
1235          40
1236          20
1236          30
1236          40
1237          50
9876          10
9876          20
9876          30
9876          40
9877          10
9877          40
9877          50
9878          10
9878          20
9878          30
9878          50
```

After several crazy subqueries (too long to post here) I can get to a table that shows me what each vendor is missing, and my thought is to then JOIN to that table based on those missing items and then show the vendors who have the refined list.

result should look like (comma separated or not doesn't matter, just easier to read)

```
vender_1 | product_id   |   missing_product_id   | vendor_2
1234       10,20,30,40          50                 9876,9878
1235        10,40            20,30,50              9878
1236        20,30,40           10,50               9877
1237        50              10,20,30,40            1234
```

or

```
vender_1 | product_id   |   missing_product_id   | vendor_2
1234           10          
1234           20              
1234           30           
1234           40                                 
1234                              50                 9876
1234                              50                 9878
```

etc...

Comment: Consider handling display issues in application code

Comment: yes. not worried about display issues. Just looking to get results :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT v.vendor_id
FROM vendors v  -- Shouldn't this be called vendorProducts ?
WHERE v.product_id IN (10, 20, 30, 40, 50) 
GROUP BY v.vendor_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT v.product_id) = 5;
```

For multiple vendors, you can extend the above logic.  The idea is to join the table together to get a list of pairs of vendors and all the products that they together have.  Then, do the same logic as above:

```
SELECT v.vendor_id1, v.vendor_id2
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT v1.vendor_id as vendor_id1, v2.vendor_id as vendor_id2,
             (CASE WHEN n.n = 1 THEN v1.product_id ELSE v2.product_id END) as product_id
      FROM vendors v1 JOIN
           vendors v2
           ON v1.product_id <> v2.product_id AND
              v1.vendor_id < v2.vendor_id CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT 1 as n UNION ALL SELECT 2) n
      UNION ALL
      -- Then include the singletons, just in case
      SELECT v.vendor_id, NULL, v.product_id
      FROM vendors v
     ) v
WHERE v.product_id IN (10, 20, 30, 40, 50) 
GROUP BY v.vendor_id1, v.vendor_id2
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT v.product_id) = 5;
```

You can actually do the product filtering in the subquery -- to make the query more efficient.  As for making this more general, the "5" is the number of items.  I don't know how the ultimate query is being constructed.

EDIT II:

This is a hard problem with a lot of data.  Here is another approach that might work better if you have lots of products and few vendors:

```
select v1.*, v2.*
from (select vendor_id,
             max(product_id = 1) as p1,
             max(product_id = 2) as p2,
             max(product_id = 3) as p3,
             max(product_id = 4) as p4,
             max(product_id = 5) as p5,
      from vendors
      where product_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
      group by vendor_id
     ) v1 join
     (select vendor_id,
             max(product_id = 1) as p1,
             max(product_id = 2) as p2,
             max(product_id = 3) as p3,
             max(product_id = 4) as p4,
             max(product_id = 5) as p5,
      from vendors
      where product_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
      group by vendor_id
     ) v2
     on (v1.p1 + v2.p1) > 0 and
        (v1.p2 + v2.p2) > 0 and
        (v1.p3 + v2.p3) > 0 and
        (v1.p4 + v2.p4) > 0 and
        (v1.p5 + v2.p5) > 0;
```

Note:  If one vendor has all the products, then it will appear paired with every other vendor.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. I'm looking for something a bit more expansive. So the order input can change both products and size, which I can accommodate with variables etc. But in most scenarios, it would be rare to have all items at a single vendor, as in my example, no vendor does have all 5. So how do I match 2 vendors to satisfy all 5 products?

Comment: @DanielGurzi . . . Oh, that makes the question much more interesting.

Comment: wow. I'm still checking it out. My database is pretty big so this is taking a while to go through. In the meantime, i'm trying to suss out what all this means. Can you explain the n.n = 1 and what that's doing? and once this finishes, I'll send you a more final version to show a bit more of how it works in the wild

Comment: @DanielGurzi . . . That subquery joins two vendors.  For this two work, the products need to be on separate rows, with the two vendor ids on each row (that is "A, 1"/"B, 2" --> "A, B, 1"/"A, B, 2").  The `CROSS JOIN` and `n` and `CASE` is used for this unpivot.

Comment: thanks for the help. I was able to use some of your ideas here. Ultimately, I ended up doing something longer and harder, LOL, but it works very quickly. Essentially I looked at what each vendor was missing, and then matched second vendors to those missing items. And it gave me a list of second vendors to pair with each initial vendor. I'll see if I can write it out in a simple way to share